# Applescript - How to iterate over tracks

Tags: applescript, itunes

I'm a newbie in applescript. I was trying to learn it from various sources, such as [Doug's site](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/info02.php), [macscripter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=25631) and this [forum](http://forum.soft32.com/mac/Script-iTunes-ftopict39588.html)

Just for learning purposes, I was trying to print on the screen all the tracks names using this code:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set myTracks to (tracks of library playlist 1)
    repeat with aTrack in myTracks
        get name of aTrack
    end repeat
end tell
```

But it only prints one track name, probably the last one...

So, how is the best way to iterate over a list?

TIA,

Bob

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is fine; the reason nothing seems to happen is that all `get ...` does is look up a value and return it.  However, you don't do anything with the returned value, so it is ignored, and only the last iteration of the loop returns anything.  You need to do something (anything) inside the loop which is visible to the outside world: assign to a variable, display a dialog, whatever.

If you want to collect a list of the names of items, you can do the following:

```
tell application "iTunes"
  set trackNames to {}
  repeat with aTrack in tracks of library playlist 1
    set trackNames to trackNames & name of aTrack
  end repeat
end tell
```

However, you can tighten this up.  One powerful feature of AppleScript is that just as you can get the name of a track, you can get the name of every track in a list and iterate over that:

```
tell application "iTunes"
  set trackNames to {}
  repeat with aName in name of tracks of library playlist 1
    set trackNames to trackNames & aName
  end repeat
end tell
```

But at this point, you don't even need the loop, and you can use the much simpler

```
tell application "iTunes" to name of tracks of library playlist 1
```

And as a bonus, it'll be *much* faster: in a quick test I did, the three versions took 16.189 seconds, 32.656 seconds, and *0.296 seconds*, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

I think your answer is valid. I believe the result in the Apple script editor column only prints the last result of your script. If you have a look in The Event and replies, you should see the answers being properly returned by your script.

I tried myself, using this script :

```
tell application "iTunes"
set myTracks to (tracks of library playlist 1)

repeat with i from 1 to number of items in myTracks
    get name of item i of myTracks
end repeat
```

Can see that in the Replies :

- get name of file track id 4050 of
  library playlist id 3379 of source id
  41

  ```
  --> "Le deserteur"
  ```
- get name of file track id 4051 of
  library playlist id 3379 of source id
  41

  ```
  --> "Le lyon est mort ce soir"
  ```

ALso, just to make sure this does work, you can try that :

```
 tell application "iTunes"
    set myTracks to (tracks of library playlist 1)

    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in myTracks
        display dialog name of item i of myTracks as string
    end repeat

end tell
```

So it works, you only have to do what you want to do before the end of your loop.

Also, I would suggest the offical Apple documentation : AppleScript Language Guide. Free and very complete to start.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add that these types of AppleScript scripts still work on MacOS Catalina, but because iTunes has been renamed to "Music", you will have to change `tell application "iTunes"` to `tell application "Music"`